# Cache aligning data structures

Tags: caching, memory-management, memory-alignment

I want to align data structures in my application to cache lines. Here is a simple scenario :

```
typedef struct container {
  int a;
  int b;
} cont __attribute__((aligned(64));

int main() {
  cont *a;
  a = malloc( sizeof(cont) * 10);
  printf("%p", a);
  return 0;
}
```

In this case I thought that the starting address of the array will be cache aligned i.e. start at 64 byte boundary. But the address that is printed is 0x9dd008 which is not aligned to 64 byte boundary. Am I missing something in this implementation?

Comment: If you still have any questions, please let me know.  I would be happy to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating from the heap, and the address returned is determined by `malloc()`.  Since the code is already compiled, the compiler can't enforce the requested address alignment.

If you try allocating `cont` on the stack you should see the correct alignment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `posix_memalign()` to allocate memory with a specific memory alignment. In C11 you also have the opportunity to use `aligned_alloc()` that will provide the same functionality as `posix_memalign()` in other platforms (beside POSIX) as well.